# Webview javascript code img buton click

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I want to 
td id="IOMToolbarActive1_kaydet_b" Auto click

```
<tr>
    <td><img src="../../images/toolimages/seperator.jpg" border="0"></td>
    <td id="IOMToolbarActive1_kaydet_b" width="25">
        <img src="../../images/toolimages/save.jpg" style="cursor:hand;CURSOR:pointer;" alt="Kaydet" onmouseover="this.src='../../images/toolimages/save_a.jpg'" onmouseout="this.src='../../images/toolimages/save.jpg'" onclick="return AlanKontrolveKayit();" border="0">
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: İmacros TAG POS=1 TYPE=IMG ATTR=ALT:Kaydet working

Comment: So you want to auto click the `img` tag when you first enter page?

Comment: yes auto click the img

Answer (score 0):

If you want auto click the `img` tag

```
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);
WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();


webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);


mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");

mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        mWebView.loadUrl( "javascript:window.onload= (function(){ document.getElementById('IOMToolbarActive1_kaydet_b').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].click();})();");
    }
});

// ...
```

If you want to auto click the `id="IOMToolbarActive1_kaydet_b"` tag, replace

```
mWebView.loadUrl( "javascript:window.onload= (function(){ document.getElementById('IOMToolbarActive1_kaydet_b').getElementsByTagName('img')[0].click();})();");
```

with

```
mWebView.loadUrl( "javascript:window.onload= (function(){ document.getElementById('IOMToolbarActive1_kaydet_b').click();})();");
```